# Breakpoints set from Python Breakpoints packages didn't work

Tags: python, sublimetext2, breakpoints, pdb

I just installed sublime text 2, the control package and the python breakpoints. Well, I am trying to use the breakpoint functionality of these packages but it isn't working. I am using a Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

This is just a test code

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  
p = 'Hello World'
print p
```

When I run it, the follwing output message is sent:

```
> /home/teste.py(5)<module>()
-> p = 'Hellow World'
(Pdb) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/teste.py", line 5, in <module>
    p = 'Hellow World'
  File "/home/teste.py", line 5, in <module>
    p = 'Hellow World'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 49, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 68, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
```

I will be glad for any help.

Comment: I don't use sublime but how are you running this? `BdbQuit` is normally caused when you issue the EOF char (say `Ctrl-D` on Linux) at the PDB interpreter.

Comment: Well, I run code using the command  Ctrl-B, that is the key shortcut for Build in sublime text 2.

Comment: A little Googling tells me Sublime Text doesn't handle any kind of embedded REPL (interpreter). So your breakpoints are working fine but Sublime is immediately dropping you out of the REPL. There are various projects (like [this one](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL)) meant to address this, but out of the box this is how it works. The `BdbQuit` is just the normal exception for the way Sublime exits it.

Comment: Well, so if I run the code, for example, from the terminal pdb will work?

Comment: It should. If it doesn't, you have another problem. I would like to emphasize that it seems to be working now, but something (presumably Sublime) is telling it to exit immediately.

Comment: You are rigth. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so there's an answer to this question:

It seems that Sublime Text does not natively support any kind of [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). The breakpoint above is working but exits with a `BdbQuit` exception, raised when the pdb REPL receives [EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file), which is a common way to 'quit' (also works on bash, zsh, python interpreter, etc.). Apparently Sublime Text is sending this immediately since it cannot open an REPL.

## The Non-Integrated Solution

Simply don't run the code with Sublime Text. Activating this breakpoint either via the command line (`python my_script.py`) or Python interpreter (by importing and running) would indeed drop you into the pdb interpreter as expected.

## The Integrated Solution

There are a few projects (like [this one](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) I mentioned in the comments above) that can add REPL support to Sublime. I don't personally use Sublime Text so I can't recommend one, nor do I even know if that one is good.

If any Sublime experts come along, please feel free to improve this answer or suggest alternatives in comments.